# Manage Glance Interface in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone

I have made one app for iPhone in Xcode 7. Now I need to add Glance Interface to the watch app. However I have migrated all the code to Xcode 8, and in the latest version of Xcode 8, Glance Interface is not showing. I have followed some tutorial to add it manually, but in storyboard, its not showing the option to add Glance Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glances have been (silently) removed in watchOS 3. Instead, you can put apps in your dock, which shows the main screen. Apps you have placed in the dock load really fast. You can open the dock by pressing the side button. (it formerly opened your favorite contacts)

[image: watchOS 3 dock]